# FluentNHibernate mapping for Dictionary

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

What is the best way of mapping a simple Dictionary property using Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map a list as a dictionary:

```
HasMany(x => x.Customers)
  .AsMap();
```

I have not used it; so cannot give an example.

Have look at the wiki: <strike>[Cached version of the page](http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:z5uuv8EzVTMJ:wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/diff/StandardMappingCollectionTypes+site:wiki.fluentnhibernate.org+collection&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk), [Actual page](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/diff/StandardMappingCollectionTypes)</strike> *I have given the cached version of the page as the site seems to be down.*

Comment: This doesn't really help the user. Surely he was able to look up the correct method, however the *usage* of the method is not obvious.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class PersistedData 
{
    public virtual IDictionary<key, value> Dictionary { get; set; }
}

public class PersistedDataMap : ClassMap<PersistedData>
{
    HasMany(x => x.Dictionary)
            .Table("dict_table")
            .KeyColumn("column_id")
            .AsMap<string>("key")
            .Element("value");
}
```

This will properly map `Dictionary` to table `dict_table` and use `column_id` to associate it to the base id.

As a side note, if you would like to use an Enum as the Key in the dictionary, it should be noted that `NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType<MyEnum>` can be used in place of the string in `.AsMap<string>` to use the string value instead of the Ordinal.

Answer (score 6):

Using a simple class relationship such as the following:

```
public class Foo {
    public virtual IDictionary<string, Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual int Value { get; set; }
}
```

You can map this with Fluent NHibernate in this way:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Bars)
       .AsMap(x => x.Type);
```

Where `Bar.Type` is used as the key field into the dictionary.