# How do I map a typed Dictionary in fluent nHibernate using automapping?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

My class:

```
[PersistClass]
public class ExternalAccount
{
    public virtual AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }

    public ExternalAccount()
    {
        Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

The Dictionary is not getting mapped. I understand that automapping doesn't work by default with Dictionaries, how do I configure the mapping? All Parameters is is a list of key/value pairs - so I would expect them to be stored in a table with a foreign key to the externalaccount table. I know I can do this with another class - but it makes access to the parameters in the class more difficult - I'd rather have to configure the complexity once.

Please bear in mind I am new Fluent and to nHibernate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple class relationship such as the following:

```
public class Foo {
    public virtual IDictionary<string, Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual int Value { get; set; }
}
```

You can map this with Fluent NHibernate in this way:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Bars)
       .AsMap(x => x.Type);
```

Where Bar.Type is used as the index field into the dictionary.

[FluentNHibernate mapping for Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410716/fluentnhibernate-mapping-for-dictionary)